# Gradle Firebase Sync - codePointAt(int)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I added the following lines to appropriate places in gradle files:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

dependencies{
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But sync failed, Gradle throws that error message:

**Error: No signature of method: java.lang.String.codePoints() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: codePointAt(int)**

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: is this your project level or app level file?

Comment: //project:

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}



// app level:
dependencies{
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: I am facing same problem. Are you able to fix this issue?

Comment: It was like that at first:

dependencies{
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
}

I changed it like that:

dependencies{
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}

and compileSdkVersion must be the last version:

android {
    //buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 27
}